tkinter: what is the difference between transient() and wm_transient()?
Using tkinter in Python. Created a dialog box from tk.Toplevel()
After reading various posts and docs:
    self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    self.wm_transient(self._mainwin)
    self.transient(self._mainwin)
    self.wait_visibility()
    self.grab_set()
    self.update_idletasks()  # draw
    self.wait_window(self)

Just curious as to what the difference is between wm_transient() and transient()? Do I need both or only one of them?

Here is link: https://onexception.dev/news/1345430/tkinter-transient-methods

FYI site returns 502 Bad gateway

transient is an alias to wm_transient. tkinter create aliases of those wm_xxxx functions without the prefix wm_.
Refer to the source code of tkinter.

More specifically: this line of the source code (transient = wm_transient)

got it thanks. Just out of curiousity. Why do this? Why have an alias for the same thing?

@JohnA It is better to ask the developers of tkinter.
